# IF condition Python "local variable 'monthlyPayment' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, if-statement

In the following example, I get an error

```
“local variable 'monthlyPayment' referenced before assignment”
```

The following is my code

```
def getMonthlyPayment(self, annualInterestRate, loanAmount, numberOfYears, loan):

    if loan == 0 and (annualInterestRate * 1 - loanAmount) >= 2 and numberOfYears <= 3:
        monthlyPayment = min((annualInterestRate * 1 - loanAmount), 10)
        return monthlyPayment
    elif loan == 1 and (annualInterestRate * 2 - loanAmount) >= 2 and numberOfYears <= 3:
        monthlyPayment = min((annualInterestRate * 2 - loanAmount), 20)
        return monthlyPayment
    elif loan > 1 and (annualInterestRate * 4 - loanAmount) >= 2 and numberOfYears <= 3:
        monthlyPayment = min((annualInterestRate * 4 - loanAmount), 20)
        return monthlyPayment
    else:
        monthlyPayment = 'Not Qualify'
        return monthlyPayment
```

Comment: Your code is not properly formatted

Comment: Also remove all the `return monthlyPayment ` except the last one

Comment: I did that before , and all of the scenario only returned 'Not Qualify'

Comment: Then there is logical issue with your `if/elif` conditions. I do not think `annualInterestRate * 1 -loanAmount` is what you need

Comment: Provide the exact line number in your code where the error is occurred?

Comment: Remember to start your question with a statement of the problem, even if this just recaps the title. Ensure that the full error message is included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper structure for multiple else if statements is

```
if (condition):
  monthlypayment = something
elif (condition2):
  monthlypayment = something2
elif (condition3):
  monthlypayment = something3
else:
  monthlypayment = something4
```

So with your if statement formatted correctly, monthlypayment will be assigned a value only once.  Per @anonymous's comment above, you can then end the function with `return monthlypayment`

Assuming this function is part of a class definition you need self or the @staticmethod decorator.  If you are writing non object-oriented code, you can dispense with the self.

```
def getMonthlyPayment(self,annualInterestRate,loanAmount,numberOfYears,loan):
    if  loan == 0 and (annualInterestRate * 1 - loanAmount) >= 2 and numberOfYears <= 3:
       monthlyPayment = min((annualInterestRate * 1 - loanAmount), 10)
    elif   loan == 1 and (annualInterestRate * 2 - loanAmount) >= 2 and numberOfYears <= 3:
       monthlyPayment = min((annualInterestRate * 2 - loanAmount), 20)
    elif   loan > 1 and (annualInterestRate * 4 - loanAmount) >= 2 and numberOfYears <= 3:
       monthlyPayment = min((annualInterestRate * 4 - loanAmount), 20)
    else:
       monthlyPayment='Not Qualify'
    return monthlyPayment
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not properly formatted. Also there is not need for multiple `return`. Remove all the return except the last one.

Also, you are not using `self` anywhere in the function, use [`@staticmethod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#staticmethod) decorator with the class function.

Below is the code, assuming all your logic is correct:

```
@staticmethod
def getMonthlyPayment(annualInterestRate,loanAmount,numberOfYears,loan):
    if loan ==0 and (annualInterestRate*1-loanAmount)>=2 and numberOfYears<=3:
        monthlyPayment = min((annualInterestRate * 1 -loanAmount),10)
    elif loan ==1 and (annualInterestRate*2-loanAmount)>=2 and numberOfYears<=3:
        monthlyPayment = min((annualInterestRate * 2-loanAmount),20)
    elif loan >1 and (annualInterestRate*4-loanAmount)>=2 and numberOfYears<=3:
        monthlyPayment = min((annualInterestRate * 4 -loanAmount),20)
    else:
        monthlyPayment='Not Qualify'
    return monthlyPayment
```